# dropfield transform sink connector: (STRUCT) type doesn't have a mapping to the SQL database column type

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I created a sink connector from kafka to mysql.
After transform in sink connector's config and deleting some columns I get this error whereas whithout transform it works:

(STRUCT) type doesn't have a mapping to the SQL database column type

```
{
    "name": "mysql-conf-sink",
    "config": {
      "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
      "tasks.max": "3",

      "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
      "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
      "topics": "mysql.cars.prices",
      "transforms": "dropPrefix,unwrap",

      "transforms.dropPrefix.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
      "transforms.dropPrefix.regex": "mysql.cars.prices",
      "transforms.dropPrefix.replacement": "prices", 
  
      "transforms.timestamp.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
      "transforms.timestamp.target.type": "Timestamp",
      "transforms.timestamp.field": "date_time",
      "transforms.timestamp.format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
  

      "errors.tolerance": "all",
      "errors.log.enable": "true",
      "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
  
  
      "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/product",
      "connection.user": "kafka",
      "connection.password": "123456",
  
      "transforms": "ReplaceField",
      "transforms.ReplaceField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
      "transforms.ReplaceField.blacklist": "id, brand",


            
      "insert.mode": "insert",

      "auto.create": "true",
      "auto.evolve": "true",

      "batch.size": 50000


    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put `"transforms"` key more than once in your JSON, which isn't valid.

Try with one entry

```
"transforms": "unwrap,ReplaceField,dropPrefix",
```

You are getting the error because you have overrode the value, and `unwrap`, specifically, is no longer called, so you have nested Structs.

The blacklist property got renamed to `exclude`, by the way - https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/replacefield.html#properties